# How do I get the current data in order from an ng-grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

In my web-app I've got 2 ng-grids.  The second is bound to the first grids selectedItems, which is working fine.  The problem is I want to get the list of elements in the second grid (ideally with any sorting applied to in the second list reflected in the data) so I can submit changes to a database.

So the question is how can I access the data on the second grid, if I try:

```
surveyModel.surveySelectedSectionsGrid.data
```

I get back the string that I used to setup the grid options which says:

```
surveyModel.surveySectionGrid.selectedItems
```

What I want instead is the actual data model being used for the second grid.

Here are my two grid options definitions:

```
    surveySectionGrid: {
        data: 'surveyModel.surveySections',
        multiSelect:true,
        selectedItems:[],
        showFilter:true,
        columnDefs: [
                { field: 'name', displayName: 'Questions/Sections' },
                { field: 'sectionTypeDescription', displayName: 'Section Type' },
                { displayName: 'Edit',
                  field:'sectionId',
                  cellTemplate:'<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()"><span ng-cell-text><button ng-click="gotoEditSection(row.getProperty(col.field))">Edit {{row.getProperty(col.field)}}</button></span></div>'
                }
                ]
    },
    surveySelectedSectionsGrid: {
        data: 'surveyModel.surveySectionGrid.selectedItems',
        multiSelect:false,
        selectedItems:[],
        showFilter:true,
        columnDefs: [
                { field: 'name', displayName: 'Selected Sections for Survey' }
                ]
    }
```

**Some possible ideas I've come across**

The grid's rendereredRows property is an array that has entity objects that correspond to my original elements in the data but based on the name of the array it sounds like if elements are off screen they won't show up in this list.

I've found as a temporary work-around I can call selectAll(true) on my secondary grid then use the selectedItems array then call selectAll(false) but a more direct solution would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Was able to confirm OP's issue with [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/QD6gIg?p=preview). If all elements are visible on an ng-grid object, renderedRows will have the correct number of elements. Otherwise, renderedRows will have < gridOptions.data.length objects to save memory.

The grid's renderedRows object should be what you're looking for. It has all the objects that are currently rendered in HTML (including those that are off screen) from the data array passed to the ng-grid object.

Source: I modified the ngGridCsvExportPlugin to only include filtered items. I used the renderedRows object and it worked like a charm. Edit: With less than 20 elements, it works well. With more than that, this solution breaks down and the best solution seems to be to use selectAll.

Hope this helps,

Brent

Comment: Hi Brent thanks for the reply, my concern is that the grid does "virtualization" and I believe if there's more than 50 items then they aren't all rendered (I saw this number somewhere in the code for a limit to begin virtualization).  Have you used renderedRows with more than 50 rows by chance?

Comment: I haven't (my use case has <20 elements). 

I just wrote a plnkr to test with more than 50 elements and it seems you're right - by adding a debug line to print out the $scope object every time a row was selected, I was able to confirm only 16 of the 50 elements were loading into the renderedRows object. http://plnkr.co/edit/QD6gIg?p=preview

Comment: @shaunhusain, a little late, but [check this out](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.angularjs/3778). Seems there's an option to increase the threshold for how many rows are virtualized. The default value is 50, but you can set the virtualizationThreshold variable in your GridOptions object to any number that you want. It seems it would affect performance, but it might make renderedRows a viable option.

Comment: thanks, I may play around with this, for the list I'm currently using it's not more than the default threshold, but I haven't taken the time yet to investigate if renderedRows gives me the rows in order based on the sorting applied by the user.  Basically I'm trying to use one of the grids as a drag and drop area where questions can be sorted and associated with a survey.  As is the association is working fine but I haven't gone back to that code yet to attempt to fix the ordering capabilities. I'll report back once I get back to it.